# how to send ipc signal in java

Tags: java, ipc

I search for a simple example of sending and catching signals in java.

Something like this:

```
public class App1{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int signal_num=2;
    IPC-Signal.send(signal_num, "App2");
  }
}
```

and on the other side:

```
public class App2{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int signal_num=2;     
    add_listener(signal_num);
  }
}
```

I dont want to use 3rd party application.

The idea is to call a java app that send signal to another java app(on the same server) whenever something happens. This came by to mind because currently I check if that something happened every X seconds. And by that way I can be notify when that something happens.

Comment: What IPC signals are you talking about?  Please give a specific example relative to a specific operating system.

Comment: I want it to be for all OS (win/linux/unix). I'm very new to this.

Comment: I've opened new question that clarify my question. I cant delete this one because there is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are actually talking like signals as sent using `kill` on Linux and Unix.

The bad news is that Sun/Oracle does not officially support a way to either send or catch these signals in Java code.  The best I can find is the ["Integrating Signal and Exception Handling"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html) page, which tells you have to integrate with the OS-specific signalling mechanism in native code.

If you are new to Java, I suggest that you treat this problem as "too hard".

Comment: I think you didnt get what I want.